# jQuery UI for form confirmation

Tags: jquery, forms, user-interface, dialog, confirmation

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I've already visited every single question about jQuery Dialog & Forms, but still have an issue.

I'm trying to implement a jQuery Confirmation Dialog on my form. The window actually appears without issues, but when I click "Confirm", the form isn't submitted...

This is the Javascript :

```
        // Form validation
        $(function(){
            var currentForm;
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Confirm': function(e) {
                            currentForm.submit();
                            return true;
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            $("#news-listing").submit(function(e){
                currentForm=$(this);
                if($("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open"))
                {
                    return false;
                } 
            });
});
```

And there is the HTML

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin ?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form action="news/action/delete" id="news-listing">
<table id="users-listing">
    <tr>
        <th class="id">ID</th>
        <th class="title">Title</th>
        <th class="url">URL</th>
        <th class="modify">Modify</th>
        <th class="checkcell">Delete</th>
    </tr>   
    <tr class='alt'>
        <td class='id'>".$news['news_id']."</td>";
        <td class='title'>".$news['news_title']."</td>";
        <td>".$this->News->get_url($news['news_id'])."</td>";
        <td class='modify'><a href="modify/1">Modify</a></td>;
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

EDIT : 
Here is my new code, the HTML does not change. Now I have the dialog, but confirm button doesn't submit, cancel button works well.

```
$(function() {   
                // Get the current form object 
                var currentForm = $("#news-listing");
                // Initialize dialog
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Confirm': function() {
                            currentForm.submit();
                            return true;
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Validate the form
                $("#news-listing").validate({
                    rules:{
                        "delete[]":"required"
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(e){
                        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Have you taken a view in the errorconsole of Firefox, Chrome or Safari? Maybe you made an javascript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `currentForm` is `undefined` when this line is executed:

```
currentForm.submit();
```

An error will be thrown because `undefined` does not have a `submit` method!

You attempt to set the value of `currentForm` in the `submit` event handler of the form itself, so you are suffering from something of a chicken and egg problem. You need to assign the form element to `currentForm` outside of the event handler:

```
$(function() {    
    var currentForm = $("#news-listing");
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        //Dialog options...
        //currentForm.submit() will now work here
    });
    $("#news-listing").submit(function(e) {
        //Event handler...
        //This will be executed when currentForm.submit() is called
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time ! Your solution removed the "undefined" error, but "confirm" button still does not submit the form, without any error thrown.

Comment: What is the `submit` event handler meant to do? Currently it will always return false. If it's meant to check if the dialog is open, you want the `isOpen` method, not `open`.

Comment: The submit handler must open the dialog for confirmation, if "confirm" is clicked, then it actually submit the form.

Comment: Ok I found my answer : just replace "currentForm.submit()" by an "document.getElementById().submit()". I don't know why, but jQuery Selector inside Dialog method are unavailable...

Answer (score 0):

`currentForm` variable needs to be initialize with form element.

change

```
var currentForm;
```

to

```
var currentForm = document.getElementById("news-listing");
```